# Pandas: how to get the mean after group by

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the mean RT which is the time given a user and given their response. What I did was use group by and then the mean but that gives me a number which is not the mean.

This is an example of the data:

```
Person ID   value   word   rt   emotional_w
0           V   CHOQUE     116    TRUE
0           A   SILLA      434    TRUE
0           R   BRAZO      480    FALSE
1           A   LLUVIA     1091   FALSE
1           R   SOLEDAD    637    TRUE
1           R   EDAD       6376   TRUE
```

This is what I did:

```
rt_mean = df.groupby(['Person ID', 'emotional_w'])['rt'].mean()
```

This returns this (the numbers above are only a few so this shows something very different):

```
Person ID   emotional_w    rt
0            False         9.05166894115559E+145
0            True          3.76010399264845E+108
1            False         2.56285856539796E+162
1            True          3.0308641569192E+118
```

The thing is, given my data, that is nowhere near the actual mean so how could I get it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

double check your data and types, the provided code works as expected:

```
df.groupby(['Person ID', 'emotional_w'])['rt'].mean()
```

output:

```
Person ID  emotional_w
0          False           480.0
           True            275.0
1          False          1091.0
           True           3506.5
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why it doesn't work for me, it says it's  dtype: float64 so it should work...

Comment: why don't you post the exact dataframe for which it fails?

Comment: the dataframe is a bit big to upload it here but it's here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oyix8ePjx8Cgj2pbWWOvmRngM-g5k2EzoSWxN65eZ4E/edit?usp=sharing